# WKWebview Misdirected Request

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I am creating an iOS webview and I am using the `WKWebView` class.
The main page consists of a user login page however when I enter my credentials I am redirected to a blank page with this message:

> Misdirected Request This client needs a new connection for this requested host name does not match the Server Name Indication (SNI) in use for this connection.

Could it be because the request is being made to a different domain (i.e. the backend) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to SSL Certificates. i.e. separate SSL certificates needed to be issued for the front and back ends.